# Accidently suspended laptop while the installation process was going on for upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: software-installation, software-center

When I forcedly restarted and after signing in the screen light is on for some time with mouse pointer and then  it repeatedly keeps on prompting for password with  an interval of 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the problem you describe, you should be able to boot in `upstart` mode in your GRUB menu advanced option.

If you're on a Ubuntu only machine, the GRUB menu doesn't show by itself, you will have to press the `Shift` key (or `Esc` on a few PC) during boot in order to see it appearing.

From there, you will be able to fix your packages by using
`apt-get install --fix-missing` as a first option. Then reboot and see if you are able to get to the log in screen.

Otherwise I'll ask you for more information.

Comment: How do I get GRUB Menu?.I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: When I turned on the menu and pressed F12 for I got the boot menu in which I can see the following.

Comment: I have the following option. Under UEFI BOOT :Ubuntu, Under other option :BIOS setup, BIOS Flash update, Diagnostic, change boot mode setting. Plz assist.

Comment: @MUTHUANAND when you just have pressed the button to turn your computer on, press the `Shift` key several time until you see the GRUB menu.
From there select `advanced options` and you'll be able to choose booting in `upstart` mode.


Just to clarify, pressing F12 got you into the BIOS, but this is not the way to go, BIOS and GRUB menus are 2 different things.

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying it for quite some time but not able to get GRUB Menu despite tapping /holding shift key  in several attempts.

Comment: From other posts I got that for some devices `Esc` work whereas `Shift` doesn't, maybe give it a try.

Comment: Thank you. I have lots of upstart, for instance (Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-42-generic (upstart)) and up to 4.4.0-96-generic. Which one should I select.

Comment: you can choose the uppermost one, but the one you choose will have no incidence in resolving your issue